# How to check if two similar calls to database return same the data in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to check if two same back to back calls to the DB from PHP return the same data,

I have a setTimeoutFunction in javascript which call a function on the server which inturn calls the database , the rough structure would be something like this

```
  function getOnlineUsers(){
      ajaxCall({type:'get',method:'getOnlineUsersDB'},getOnlineUsersCallBack);
    setTimeOut(1000);
    }

function getOnlineUsersCallBack(jsonObj){
//do something online only if 'jsonObj' is different from last jsonObj
}
```

My server-side function in PHP

```
$cacheData; // variable to cache data from previous calls to the DB

function getOnlineUserDB(){

$sql="select onlineusers from someTable ";

$data=getFromDbAndCastArray($sql);

if($data!=$cacheData){
                $cacheData=$data;
                return json_encode($data); //something new is returned since the last time
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

}
```

Basically I don't want to run the callBack to the Ajax call if the data recieved is the same between subsequent call .
I tried doing it by trying to cache the data in a global variable in php but failed.

I could try to check this in the front end too but not sure which is the best way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach

1. Declare global variable in Javascript.
2. Store value in global variable received from server.
3. Pass global variable to server in Ajax call,for first call, value of global variable would be blank.
4. On PHP side, if argument received value is not blank, create an array from received value.
5. Store result of query in array.
6. compare both arrays and accordingly return result.